# How to yii2 REST API in shared host?

Tags: api, rest, yii2, shared-hosting, yii2-basic-app

I'm trying to host a rest api with yii2 basic template. My application structure is this:

```
+ web
  +.htaccess
  +index.php
+ config
+ controllers
...
+ api
  + config
  + modules
    + v1
      + controllers
  .htaccess
  index.php
```

I'm bit newbie in host process, so: 
Where should I put the api directory? public_html ? Or should I leave this structure and modify the permissions ?

I think this is the correct structure, but when I try to GET some URI, I get the 404 http error.

```
+ public_html(or www, or web)
      +.htaccess
      +index.php        
      + api
        + config
        + modules
          + v1
            + controllers
        .htaccess
        index.php
```

Someone has faced this situation? 
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I've only done this using the Yii advanced application template, but it looks similar. Direct your web calls to the api-folder where api/index.php will handle your call. Typically, an API subdomain like `api.yourdomain.com` comes in handy for those API-calls.

The external link to your api should then be `http://api.yourdomain.com/v1/<controller>` given that your api/config/main.php has an entry like this (pasted from my advanced app)

```
'modules' => [
    'v1' => [
        'basePath' => '@app/modules/v1',
        'class' => 'api\modules\v1\Module'
    ]
],
```

Comment: Can you post your folder structure? Your @app references to app main folder or api folder?